# Like vwait of tcl, is there anything in C programming?

Tags: c, multithreading

Is there any way to wait for code until some variable is reset or changed in C programming like vwait in tcl?

Sample code where we can implement the same:

Here using thread, we can set the variable getout to 1 and can proceed further. 
Note: Due to some issues in code, i cannot use infinite while loop for keep on checking the variable. Is there some kind of trigger for the same task? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int getout = 0;

void *threadfunc(void *parm) 
{ 
    int x = 0;
    for (;;) {
            x++;
        if (x == 500000) {
            getout = 1;
        }
    }
    return NULL; 
}

void main () {
    pthread_t pth;
    pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadfunc,"foo");
    // wait for getout to be set to 1;
    pthread_cancel(pth); // cancel the thread after wait
}
```

Comment: Nitpick: that would have to be `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Jens Nitpick: not if you are using an embedded compiler which is running code natively without an OS.

Comment: @DaanTimmer Nitpick: Only when that implementation *documents* that it supports `void main`.

Comment: There is no need to indicate a question had been sufficiently answered, by adding things like "solved" to the title as SO knows this by the ckeckmarked question and indicates it whete necessary. Rolled back this edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you have cannot be done solely using mutex/condition, as either of them would create a race condition or undefined behavior, but needs a semaphore. If you want to use pthread primitives, you end up reinventing a semaphore.

```
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

sem_t completed;

void *threadfunc(void *parm) 
{ 
    int x = 0;
    for (;;) {
        x++;
        if (x == 500000) {
            // increase the semaphore value
            printf("Posting semaphore\n");
            sem_post(&completed);
        }
        if (! (x % 50000)) {
            printf("Yielding\n");
            // must yield with cooperative threading
            pthread_yield(); 
        }
    }
    return NULL; 
}

int main () {
    pthread_t pth;

    // 3rd parameter is value - we put in 0
    if (sem_init(&completed, 0, 0)) {
        printf("sem_init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    pthread_create(&pth,NULL,threadfunc,"foo");

    // wait for completed to be increased;
    sem_wait(&completed);
    printf("Wait completed\n");
    pthread_cancel(pth); // cancel the thread after wait

    sem_destroy(&completed);
}
```

Comment: Ran perfectly. Many thanks. But can you please explain me the use of pthread_yield();

Comment: In some cases the pthread can use cooperative scheduling; another thread might not get to run if not yielded.

Comment: Could you please be so kind and elaborate on how/where the race/UB does occur when using condtion/mutex as per my example?

Comment: Not there :D it is a perfect example of the latter - reinventing a semaphore from pthread primitives

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: Fair enough ... :-)

Comment: did i miss something? @Antti @ alk

Comment: hmm just thought that basically the spawned thread might get to run before the mutex is initialized; you want to lock it before pthread_create

Comment: Ok. I guess i need to read more regarding the same. Thanks. But i have the both practical examples.

Comment: In my example the mutex and the condition are initialised before `main()`. Why lock the mutex before actually being about to access the variable it protects, that is `getout`?

Comment: Sorry, I just got confused.

Answer (score 2):

No, you need to implement signaling your own.

This is typically down via a condition and a mutex:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int getout = 0;

pthread_cond_t cond = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *threadfunc(void *parm)
{
  int x = 0;
  for (;;)
  {
    x++;
    if (x == 500000)
    {
      pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
      getout = 1;
      pthread_cond_signal(&cond);
      pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    }
  }
  return NULL ;
}

int main(void)
{
  pthread_t pth;
  pthread_create(&pth, NULL, threadfunc, "foo");

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
  while (!getout)
    pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

  pthread_cancel(pth); // cancel the thread after wait
}
```

*Note:* This examples misses error checking of system calls for the sake of readability.

Comment: Oh. Ok. I was just looking for shortcut for implementation. I will start focusing on pthread_cond_signal. Thanks :)

Comment: As compiler started saying:incompatible type for argument 1 of ‘pthread_cond_wait’ so on quick internet search, instead of pthread_cond_wait(cond); i added pthread_cond_wait(&cond, &mutex); . But when i ran the code, it is waiting for long and never stopping. Please suggest me where i am missing?

Comment: @Vishwadeep Sry, I missed to add the call that does the actual signalling. Fixed.